# How to use a MongoDB Search Index?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am currently learning to build websites using Node JS, Express JS, MongoDB and PUG. I followed the [Mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) to understand the fundamentals and now I want to add a search bar.

I would like to profit from MongoDB search functionalities, but after 3-4 days, I am still at basket case.

Can anyone explain how it is supposed to be done? The code is exactly as described in the tutorial/example website.

Also, I really don't understand how this whole thing works, are there easier features to add or ways to 'get it' better? The debugger is an ocean of variables as I have never seen, and the slightest alterations to the example makes the whole thing sink. I am crying inside. Any help or resource is very welcomed.

Here is a link to a public repo (since it's a lot of code for a blog post).

[Public GitHub Repository](https://github.com/LizardWizard69/NodePortfolio.git)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help. Once having an attempt create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).